# android custom adapter dynamic row height

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter, row-height

I have just created my first custom adapter, which works great.
And with that, I created a rowlayout.xml for the adapter to fill.

But I have one issue, the row is not dynamic, so if I try to put a text that is longer than the row in, the row wont expand, but instead cut the text off. (see pic. here: http://tinyurl.com/paxdt3a)

Here is my rowLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <!--The second line is used for the date of the post-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Time and date"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <!--The first line is used to the post-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Post"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserPost> {
    private final Context context;
    private final List<UserPost> posts;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<UserPost> posts) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, posts);
        this.context = context;
        this.posts = posts;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

        TextView firstText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        TextView secondText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);

        //Insert the post
        firstText.setText(posts.get(position).getMessage());
        //Insert the time
        secondText.setText(posts.get(position).getDate());

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks!

**UPDATE (SOLUTION):**

Okay, so I made some changes in my rowlayout.xml, and I finally came up with this, which works!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <!--The first line is used to the post-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Post"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <!--The second line is used for the date of the post-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Time and date"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your `item layout`you have `android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"` meaning you are forcing a specific row height for all rows change to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

what simply you can do is to remove the singleLine property

```
 android:singleLine="false"
```

or you can do like this

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserPost> {
private final Context context;
private final List<UserPost> posts;

public MyAdapter(Context context, List<UserPost> posts) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, posts);
    this.context = context;
    this.posts = posts;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(text.length>MAX_LENGTH){
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout1, parent, false);
//....
}else{


    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

    TextView firstText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
    TextView secondText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);

    //Insert the post
    firstText.setText(posts.get(position).getMessage());
    //Insert the time
    secondText.setText(posts.get(position).getDate());
   }
    return rowView;
  }
}
```